# after selecting image display same image inside picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

on buttonclick I'm taking image from file system and save into database, everything is ok but I want when I select image to display that image into pictureBox1

```
 OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg" };
   if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       txtPhoto.Text = open.FileName;
   }

   string image = txtPhoto.Text;
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
   fs.Close();

   byte[] Photo = bimage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Image` property to set the Image for `PictureBox` Control.

Try This:

```
        DialogResult result= openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if(result==DialogResult.OK)
            pictureBox1.Image =new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

if you want to add it in your code

**Complete Code:**

```
       OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg" };
       if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           txtPhoto.Text = open.FileName;
       }

       string image = txtPhoto.Text;
       Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
       pictureBox1.Image = bmp;//add this line
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
       fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
       fs.Close();

       byte[] Photo = bimage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple code:

```
picturebox.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(yourimagepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg"
        };

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PictureBoxObjectName.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
openFileDialog1.Filter= "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";  

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{             
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
       picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(File);
    }
}
```

This is for selection of one image.